# WCF webmethod xml string problem

Tags: .net, xml, wcf, web-services

I have a WCF web service that returns a string to a Java based client.

```
<OperationContract()>
Function SomeSvc(ByVal fileString As String) As String
```

fileString is a bunch of xml. When the client gets the response my xmlstring is encoded as text.

```
 <s:Body u:Id="_0">
    <SomeSvcResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <SomeSvcResult>&gt; &lt;/ns2:FailureMessage&gt; &lt;/ns:BOD&gt; &lt;/ns:ConfirmDataArea&gt; &lt;/ns:Confirm&gt;
      </SomeSvcResult>
    </SomeSvcResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Why is my service returning encoded text instead of xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The service encodes your data because you defined return value as `String`. If you want to return XML use `XElement` instead.

Comment: will a non-.net client be able to handle the XElement being returned?

Comment: Yes it will be returned as pure XML and WSDL will define message content as xsd:any.